# How to trigger Enter keypress of input

Tags: javascript

I want just show an alert when enter is pressed in an input box. I tryed this but doesn't work.

This is my js code:

```
function handle(e){ 
   if(e.keyCode === 13){
        alert('pressed');
    }

    return false;
}
```

and this is my html code:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="handle()">
```

Comment: You're calling `addtodo` but the function is named `handle`

Comment: Consider using a `<form>` and just listening for the `submit` event on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `addtodo` but the function is named `handle`. You're also not passing anything to the function.

A working example:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="addtodo(event)">

function addtodo(e){ 
   if(e.keyCode === 13){
        alert('pressed');
    }
    return false;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qbt5r1o8/)**